# How to use new font in react native app?

Tags: react-native, fonts, custom-font

I am using create-react-native-app. I am not using 'android studio or anything', Also i am using sublime text editor and  expo mobile app to see the output in mobile device only.

I want to import new font. i don't know flow what should add first.

thanks in advance,

Comment: Here are the Expo docs - https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-custom-fonts.html

Comment: but expo...? i am not using expo editor...i should import this import { Font } from 'expo';'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expo covers this in their docs pretty well. When you use `create-react-native-app` you're using expo, so follow their docs.

Even if you'd created your app using `react-native init <MyAppName>` you could still install their SDK...

```
npm install --save expo
```

Then just

```
import { Font } from 'expo';
```

Use this to load your font from the assets

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    Font.loadAsync({
      'open-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'),
    });
  }

  // ...
}
```

That's the gist, pretty much copy/paste from the [Expo Docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-custom-fonts.html)

Comment: im using common components around..so where do i import this import { Font } from 'expo';

Answer (score 0):

You can load the font once in your parent component like `app.js` for example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Font } from 'expo';
import Main from './src/components/Main';
import { Text } from 'react-native';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    amount: '',
    isReady: false
  };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._loadFontsAsync();
  }

  _loadFontsAsync = async () => {
    await Font.loadAsync({ FONT_NAME: require('FONT_SOURCE')});
    this.setState({ isReady: true })
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady) {
      return <Text>Loading</Text>
    }
    return (
      <Main />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fontLoaded: false,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      'helvetica': helveticaFont,
      'roboto-condensed-light': robotoCondensedLight,
      'roboto-condensed-regular': robotoCondensedRegular,
      'roboto-condensed-bold': robotoCondensedBold,
    });
    this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        {
          this.state.fontLoaded ? (
            <SignIn></SignIn>
          ) : null
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```